# Proper way to use || inside an "if" condition in a template

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to use:

```
<%= if @button_effect == "auxNo" || "mainNo" do %>
```

But only the first value (`"auxNo"`) is evaluated, not the second (`"mainNo"`).
I've tried different combinations of `()` but up to now it's not working like I wanted.
Another options would be to use "case" for more than 2 values, but, again, not being able to do it.
Can I have an example of both (`if` and `case`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check `@button_effect` in your or condition:

```
<%= if @button_effect == "auxNo" || @button_effect == "mainNo" do %>
```

If you don't do this then the value will always be truthy (either `@button_effect == "auxNo"` when it is true, or the string `"mainNo"` when it is false.)

You can also rewrite this as:

```
if @button_effect in ["auxNo", "mainNo"] do
```

Comment: Using a list is perfect for me as it covers N values. Great!